# How to scroll textview horizontally while entering text?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have an application in which i have a scroll view and i have add textview in scrollview.
I have set frame of **textview (0,0,560,200)** as i want textview width more then Iphone screen width.

Now my question is how to scroll my textview in left direction with entering text in textview at end of screen width?

That means when i reach to end of screen width by entering text, the **textview should scroll** in left as i **continue to entering text**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give the width of text entered

CGSize textSize = [yourTextview.text sizeWithFont:yourTextview.font constrainedToSize:yourTextview.contentSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    CGFloat ff=textSize.width;

Answer (score 0):

You need not use scrollview as UITextView will have scroll properties.You can make use of notification which you get while entering text.i,e "UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification" and change textview contentoffset as you want.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but how can i found the width of letter so that i can set contentoffset.i mean to say there is different width for 'l' and 'W' like other letters also.

Comment: Also how can i come to know that i reach at the screen end by entering text and now i have to set contentoffset. Please put some code if you can..thanks again